# Unity3d UNET - SpawnWithClientAuthority doesnt have authority when host

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I am having issues with SpawnWithClientAuthority when "hosting" a match with UNET in UNITY3D. If i create a stand alone server, and connect clients to it, everything works perfectly. If I host a game, where i am also a client, then for what ever reason the hosted client doesn't have authority (hasAuthority is false).

In my game PlayerObject represents my players connection, and TankPlayer is my physical player (the thing i need authority over--to do things like enable its camera).

Here is my spawn code:

```
[Command]
void CmdSpawnPlayer()
{
    GameObject player = Instantiate(m_PlayerTank);

    NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority(player, connectionToClient);

}
```

This should spawn a tank from my m_PlayerTank prefab (it has "client authority checked). Here are my inspector objects:

[NetworkManager inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgEnQ.png)

[PlayerObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D91h.png)

[_PlayerTank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24i5t.png)

Is there a way to make sure the host client has authority in my scripts? Here is where i am checking the authority:

```
new void Start ()
{
    base.Start();

    if (hasAuthority)
    {
        m_Camera.gameObject.tag = "MainCamera";
        m_Camera.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        Debug.Log("auth");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("No auth?");
    }
```

}

Comment: SOLVED!!!!!!! There is a method/callback specifically for this situation where you need to check authority inside of start:

public override void OnStartAuthority()
{

}